# Diffs between two commits using JGit in Java

Tags: java, jgit

I'm writing a program with Java using JGit.
I want to find out the differences between two commits in a project. 
So I convert two commits from String to ObjectId, but it always shows me error that the commits which I put in are not trees.
Can anyone please help me?

**Hier is the code:**

```
try (Git git = new Git(repository)) {

   ObjectId commit1 = ObjectId.fromString("123456........" );
   ObjectId commit2 = ObjectId.fromString("sfggdg........" );

   ObjectReader reader = repo.newObjectReader();

   CanonicalTreeParser oldTreeIter = new CanonicalTreeParser();
   oldTreeIter.reset(reader, commit1);
   CanonicalTreeParser newTreeIter = new CanonicalTreeParser();
   newTreeIter.reset(reader, commit2);

   System.out.println("Differences between two commits: ");

   List<DiffEntry> diffs = git.diff().setOldTree(oldTreeIter).setNewTree(newTreeIter).call();

   for (DiffEntry diff : diffs) {

        System.out.println(diff.getPath(null);

    } 
}
```

**Output:**

```
Differences between two commits:
org.eclipse.jgit.errors.IncorrectObjectTypeException: Object 123456........ is not a tree.
at org.eclipse.jgit.internal.storage.file.WindowCursor.open(WindowCursor.java:150)
at org.eclipse.jgit.treewalk.CanonicalTreeParser.reset(CanonicalTreeParser.java:214)
at com.capgemini.fis.DiffsBetweenTwoCommits.main(DiffsBetweenTwoCommits.java:57)
```

**Expected Output:** (for example)

```
Differences between two commits:
README.txt
file.h
```

Comment: This has been answered here already: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27361538/how-to-show-changes-between-commits-with-jgit. Just replace `HEAD` and `HEAD~1` with the respective commit ids.

Comment: Thank you Rüdiger! I've tried it before, but the program shows me the differences between another two commits, not the 2 commits that I put in. Can they be the parents of the two commits which I put in?

Comment: @RüdigerHerrmann you are right. I just need to replace HEAD and HEAD~1 with the respective commit ids. I misstook commit ids for tree id. I'll delete this question.