# Using JGit fetch() and check for updated files

Tags: java, jgit

Using JGit, I've checked out a branch (`branch1`). After some time, I want to fetch() and see which files have been updated (in the origin) since my last fetch.

```java
FetchResult fetchResult = m_git.fetch().setRefSpecs(new RefSpec("refs/heads/branch1")).call();

// For example:
fetchResult.getUpdatedFiles()
```

How do I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found something that worked for me.

Got most of this from a jgit cookbook: https://github.com/centic9/jgit-cookbook/blob/master/src/main/java/org/dstadler/jgit/porcelain/ShowFileDiff.java#start-of-content

The DiffEntry collection below shows me the modified files. (fyi, this can be done before a merge)

```
fetch();

// todo: isn't there a critical section here? Only within the same repo maybe. We could prevent simultaneous use of the same racfid.
Ref fetchHead;
try {
    fetchHead = m_git.getRepository().findRef("FETCH_HEAD");

    //todo: show the diff bewteen fetch-head and the current head.
    // - get object id of fetch
    // - get oid of head

    ObjectId head = m_git.getRepository().resolve(Constants.HEAD);

    AbstractTreeIterator oldTreeParser = prepareTreeParser(m_git.getRepository(), fetchHead.getObjectId());
    AbstractTreeIterator newTreeParser = prepareTreeParser(m_git.getRepository(), head);

    List<DiffEntry> diff = m_git.diff().
        setOldTree(oldTreeParser).
        setNewTree(newTreeParser).
        // setPathFilter(PathFilter.create("README.md")).
        // to filter on Suffix use the following instead
        //setPathFilter(PathSuffixFilter.create(".java")).
        call();

    for (DiffEntry entry : diff) {
        System.out.println("Entry: " + entry + ", from: " + entry.getOldId() + ", to: " + entry.getNewId());
    }
```

}

```
private static AbstractTreeIterator prepareTreeParser(Repository repository, ObjectId objectId) throws IOException {
    // from the commit we can build the tree which allows us to construct the TreeParser
    //noinspection Duplicates
    try (RevWalk walk = new RevWalk(repository)) {
        RevCommit commit = walk.parseCommit(objectId);
        RevTree tree = walk.parseTree(commit.getTree().getId());
        CanonicalTreeParser treeParser = new CanonicalTreeParser();
        try (ObjectReader reader = repository.newObjectReader()) {
            treeParser.reset(reader, tree.getId());
        }
        walk.dispose();
        return treeParser;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The granularity level of the fetch API is commits, not files. Hence fetch itself won't tell you which files were updated.

The `FetchResult` however holds detailed information about the outcome of the fetch operation.

Iterate over `FetchResult::getTrackingRefUpdates` to see all refs that were updated (should be just one in your example). For each changed ref you are interested in, the `TrackingRefUpdate` describes the result of the fetch operation of the respective ref.

First look into the `result` property to see if the overall outcome is what you asked for. For regular ref update, use `getOldObjectId` and `getNewObjectId` to diff the old and new commit.

See here how to diff with JGit: [How to show changes between commits with JGit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27361538/how-to-show-changes-between-commits-with-jgit)

Comment: This doesn't work for me.

After fetching from origin where there is indeed a change in one file (verified multiple times) fetchResult.getTrackingRefUpdates() still returns an empty collection.

Immediately after I merge the fetch_head Ref though, I see 2 merged commits in the MergeResult.