# JGit - Contents of Commit Into String

Tags: java, jgit

I need to store the contents of a commit, this would be the difference from eg. master to the latest commit, in a string.

[How to show changes between commits with JGit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27361538/how-to-show-changes-between-commits-with-jgit) The bottom answer is very similar to what I want

This is the code from the link

```
RevCommit headCommit = getHeadCommit(repository);
    RevCommit diffWith = headCommit.getParent(0);
    FileOutputStream stdout = new FileOutputStream(FileDescriptor.out);
    try (DiffFormatter diffFormatter = new DiffFormatter(stdout)) {
        diffFormatter.setRepository(repository);
        for (DiffEntry entry : diffFormatter.scan(diffWith, headCommit)) {
            diffFormatter.format(diffFormatter.toFileHeader(entry));
        }
    }
```

```
diffFormatter.format(diffFormatter.toFileHeader(entry));
```

The format() method is void, and there doesnt seem to be a way to return a string or some sort of outputstream.

I would expect there to be something along the lines of

```
String commitDiff = diffFormatter.getCommitContents(entry).toString();
```

I understand this doesnt exist in the library, but there must be something that can put the contents of a commit into something that can be turned into a String

Comment: `format` writes to the output stream that was given to the constructor if the `DiffFormatter`.

Comment: @RüdigerHerrmann So how would I change this so that the difference will go into a String?

Comment: @RüdigerHerrmann I spoke to soon, this fixed it, Thank you very much :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code was changed to

```
OutputStream output = new OutputStream() {
    private StringBuilder string = new StringBuilder();
    @Override
    public void write(int b) throws IOException {
        this.string.append((char) b );
    }

    public String toString(){
        return this.string.toString();
    }
};
RevCommit headCommit = getHeadCommit(repository);
RevCommit diffWith = headCommit.getParent(0);
try (DiffFormatter diffFormatter = new DiffFormatter(output)) {
    diffFormatter.setRepository(repository);
    for (DiffEntry entry : diffFormatter.scan(diffWith, headCommit)) {
        diffFormatter.format(diffFormatter.toFileHeader(entry));
    }
String strings = output.toString();
System.out.println(strings);
```

It is a long way of doing it but it proves it can be done
This has now stored the difference into the string

```
strings
```