# List of affected files from git.pull().call()

Tags: jgit

I'm new to JGit, so maybe I get something wrong, but I can't manage to get the result from the pull-command.
By that I mean a list of files that were affected by the pull (modified/added/deleted files,....)

I tried several things, but none of them gave me the information I need:

```java
PullResult pull_res = git.pull().setCredentialsProvider(cred).call();
MergeResult merge_res = pull_res.getMergeResult();
FetchResult fetch_res = pull_res.getFetchResult();
java.lang.System.out.println("MergeStat1: "+merge_res.getMergeStatus());
java.lang.System.out.println("####################################");
java.lang.System.out.println("MergeStat2: "+merge_res.getMergedCommits());
java.lang.System.out.println("####################################");
java.lang.System.out.println("FetchRes: "+fetch_res.getMessages());
java.lang.System.out.println("####################################");
java.lang.System.out.println("PullRes1: "+pull_res.getFetchResult());
java.lang.System.out.println("####################################");
java.lang.System.out.println("PullRes2: "+pull_res.getFetchResult().getMessages());
java.lang.System.out.println("####################################");
java.lang.System.out.println("PullRes3: "+pull_res.getFetchResult().toString());
java.lang.System.out.println("####################################");
java.lang.System.out.println("PullRes4: "+pull_res.getFetchResult().getMessages().toString());
java.lang.System.out.println("####################################");
java.lang.System.out.println("PullRes5: "+pull_res.getMergeResult());
java.lang.System.out.println("####################################");
java.lang.System.out.println("PullRes6: "+pull_res.getRebaseResult());
java.lang.System.out.println("####################################");
java.lang.System.out.println("PullRes7: "+pull_res.getFetchedFrom());
```

This results in the following output:

```
MergeStat1: Fast-forward
####################################
MergeStat2: [Lorg.eclipse.jgit.lib.ObjectId;@1....
####################################
FetchRes: 
####################################
PullRes1: org.eclipse.jgit.transport.FetchResult@3....
####################################
PullRes2: 
####################################
PullRes3: org.eclipse.jgit.transport.FetchResult@3....
####################################
PullRes4: 
####################################
PullRes5: Merge of revisions a...., 1a.. with base 1a... using strategy recursive resulted in: Fast-forward. 
####################################
PullRes6: null
####################################
PullRes7: origin
```

What can I do to get a list of all the affected files from that pull? (also *how* they were affected: modified, added, deleted..)

UPDATE

With Rüdigers answer I came to the following solution of the problem:

```java
CanonicalTreeParser newTreeIter = new CanonicalTreeParser();
ObjectId tree = git.getRepository().resolve("HEAD^{tree}");
newTreeIter.reset(reader, tree);

UsernamePasswordCredentialsProvider cred = new UsernamePasswordCredentialsProvider(USER, PASSWORD);
PullResult pull_res = git.pull().setCredentialsProvider(cred).call();

CanonicalTreeParser oldTreeIter = new CanonicalTreeParser();
tree = git.getRepository().resolve("HEAD^{tree}");
oldTreeIter.reset(reader, tree);
DiffFormatter df = new DiffFormatter(new ByteArrayOutputStream());
df.setRepository( git.getRepository() );
List<DiffEntry> entries = df.scan(oldTreeIter, newTreeIter);

for(DiffEntry entry : entries) {
    java.lang.System.out.println(entry);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Buffer the commit ID of the current branch before calling pull, for example using `git.getRepository().resolve("HEAD")`.

When pull is done, read the `HEAD` commit ID again. Now you should be able to create a diff between the two commits.

How to show the changed files between two commits has been answered here: [How to show changes between commits with JGit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27361538/how-to-show-changes-between-commits-with-jgit)

See here for a detailed discussion of JGit's diff APIs: https://www.codeaffine.com/2016/06/16/jgit-diff/